# Expo App Build Showing Device Family as iPhone Instead of iPad

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo

I am developing an application using Expo that is intended to run on Android and ios devices. During the development phase, the application builds and forms successfully. However, when I generate the final build and open it via this link(https://webapp.diawi.com/install/4JgSiB) , the device family is displayed as "iPhone" instead of "iPad". I would like to change it so that it shows "iPad".

Here is the relevant section of my info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>self-help-kiosk-mobile-app</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>com.sushanthsp.selfhelpkioskmobileapp</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
      <string>armv7</string>
      <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <integer>2</integer>
</array>

  </dict>
</plist>
```

I have included both integers 1 and 2 in the UIDeviceFamily key, which I believe should indicate support for both iPhone and iPad. Despite this, the device family is still showing as iPhone.

Has anyone experienced this issue or have any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!